# Ubuntu usb ports not working

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, usb

New install Ubuntu 14.04 and I cannot get my usb drives to recognize that there is a usb drive in the device. I have tried 4 different usb drives and none are working on the machine. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not going to be much help (sorry), but please edit your question and append the output of the command `lsusb`

Comment: Did this ever work for you, or is this something new? Is the USB setting in your BIOS set to "legacy"? Are you plugging the USB drives directly into a computer port, or a hub, or something else?

Comment: I am plugging in directly to the computer port. This is the first time using the computer as it is a fresh install.